# How to create two time ranges on TimePicker? JAVA

Tags: java, time, timepicker, localtime

I have created a TimePicker on Java. I have achieved to veto a range time (12h to 23.30h). But I want to make two different ranges of availables times, for example (12h to 15h and 19h to 23h). I have this Override created for achieving to create one range of times available:

```
public class SampleTimeVetoPolicy implements TimeVetoPolicy {


@Override
    public boolean isTimeAllowed(LocalTime time) {
        return PickerUtilities.isLocalTimeInRange(time,LocalTime.of(12,00),LocalTime.of(23,30),true);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make this two different ranges.

Example of what I execute with the actual override:

[image: Example of what I execute with the actual override:]

Thanks everyone! (The lib used is lgooddatepicker)

Comment: `return PickerUtilities.isLocalTimeInRange(...) || PickerUtilities.isLocalTimeInRange(...);`?  You could even create a `List` of ranges to make life easier

Comment: thx! it worked with the || statement. I thought that I couldn't use || on a return line. thx a lot again!

Comment: @AndresLuengoBlazquez If you think the `||` in the return statement is too hard to read, you can make an `if` statement and two or three or more `return` statements. Among seasoned programmers, `||` and `&&`  inside the `return`  statement are commonplace (and sometimes also overused IMHO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "simplest" solution might be to do something like...

```
return PickerUtilities.isLocalTimeInRange(...) || PickerUtilities.isLocalTimeInRange(...);
```

A more robust solution would be to create a `TimeRange` class (taking a start and end time of the range) which has a `contains` style method and build a `List` of them and simply loop over the list until either you complete the loop or one returns `false`